# How can I select a row properly by using dataTable 1.10.10 and bootstrap 2.3.5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have tried various combinations to select a row in dataTable 1.10.10 and bootstrap 2.3.5 but none of them are working properly. The rows are not being highlighted on selection.

If I include bootstrap 3.3.5 the whole ui gets messed up. Can anybody give me a working example ?

Comment: First, are you sure you are using the current DataTables 1.10 [BootStrap 2](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/commit/916be03336f4b362d676c57c5b4cdd8379c29cd2) integration file? And have you tried this [row selection example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html)?

Comment: I am doing exactly as you said . Still the selected row is not being highlighted.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code which handles the click event.